# python can't find file on system

Tags: python, directory, location

I am trying to run a python script on a linux server and it needs to access a list on a text file - saved in the same location that I'm running the script.

This might be just a simple formatting issue but I've tried various ways and still no luck.

Here is the code in my python file:

```py
list1 = session.target_list("C:\\root\\instapy-quickstart\\apples.txt")
session.follow_by_list(list1)
```

Getting the error:

```sh
No such file or directory: C:\root\instapy-quickstart\apples.txt
```

Comment: path is wrong, on linux server it'll look something like `/home/your_user/file.txt`. Alternatively, you can specify file location relative to the place you're running your script from, like `./apples.txt`

Comment: You should always use raw string litterals when using backslashes: `session.target_list(r"C:\root\instapy-quickstart\apples.txt") ` - note the `r` before the quote. Or just use forward slashes, even on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the same location, why you don't use the name of the file without pathway? I mean:

```
list1 = session.target_list("apples.txt")
```

Comment: @mattygee happy to hear that :).